# Are the closed and unbounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ known up to homeomorphism?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, classification

I am currently working on a problem for which this knowledge could greatly reduce the number of cases, but I have yet to find anything after searching online. Are the closed unbounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ known up to homeomorphism?

References would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt such a (useful) classification exists.

Comment: "unbounded" is not a topological invariant (e.g. $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic with $(0,\infty)$).

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: But an unbounded *closed* set is never homeomorphic to a bounded closed set.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: True, but "non-compact" would be more appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinite, complete, separable linear order with at most countably many jumps and not both a greatest and least element.

See 
http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/papers/SeparableLinearOrders2.pdf

Comment: Can you please explain more explicitly why this is related to the OP.

Comment: Yes could you please provide a little more elaboration as to exactly how this is related to my question?

Comment: @ElChapo, the answer provides a characterisation of such closed unbounded subsets, as per your request.

Comment: I think the question is looking for a useful way to list all of the homeomorphism classes of closed unbounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, rather than a necessary and sufficient criterion for a space to be homeomorphic to such a set.

Comment: Isomorphism of linear orders is essentially stricter than homeomorphism.

Comment: Well, this sort of provides an *intrinsic* characterization (not referring to the  embedding into other structures).

Answer (score 6):

For any closed subset $K$ of the usual Cantor set $\mathcal{C} \subseteq [0,1]$, consider the map which sends $K$ to the set $K \cup [2,\infty)$. Then this map explicitly reduces the problem of classifying closed subsets of the Cantor set up to homeomorphism to the problem of classifying closed non-compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ up to homeomorphism.

The classification problem for closed subsets of a Cantor space up to homeomorphism is known to be *pretty* complicated. More specifically, it is as complicated as the classification problem for countable graphs, or say, countable linear orders up to isomorphism. (These claims can be made precise using the notion of Borel reducibility. You can find the relevant theorems in [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-02/S0002-9947-00-02659-3/S0002-9947-00-02659-3.pdf) paper. But I doubt that you are looking for such technical details.)